# How to get and compare current scene name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to compare scene name but I am getting the error below:

> error CS0019: Operator `==' cannot be applied to operands of type`
>   method group' and `string'

I can't figure out how to fix this error. please help me! the error is located on the arrow

```
void CheckCurrentLevel()
{
    for(int i = 1; i < LevelAmount; i++)
    {
    --->    if (SceneManager.LoadScene == "Level" + i) {
            CurrentLevel = i;
            SaveMyGame ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One is method, one is `string`

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the **actual answer** that you selected so that others who encounter the same issue as you find their way to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SceneManager.LoadScene` is a `void` function used to load a scene. It does not return anything so you can't compare it with a string.

It looks like you want to compare the current scene `name` with `"Level" + i`. If that's true then you are looking for `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name`

```
void CheckCurrentLevel()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < LevelAmount; i++)
    {
        if (SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Level" + i)
        {
            CurrentLevel = i;
            SaveMyGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the `==` operator Checks if the values of two operands are equal or not, subject to the condition that both the operands should be same type. From the error message it is clear that `LoadScene` is defined as a method.

Your code will works fine if you use like this:

```
if (SceneManager.LoadScene(params if any) == "Level" + i)
{
    // Code here 
}
```

Subject to the condition that **LoadScene() method should return a string object** or else the return type will be a business object in this case use a string property for comparison